# Hibernate 5 not committing/saving records in Oracle DB

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions, jpa-2.0

Recently migrated my application from Hibernate 3.6.9 to 5.4.10. After that, get methods like criteria.list() is working fine, but when I use session.saveOrUpdate() it is not actually persisting in DB and not throwing any error as well.The data just gets lost.

Server - Oracle Weblogic Server 12c
Database - 10g

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">DS1</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</property>
  <property name="hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class">org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl </property>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform</property>
  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.JTASessionContext</property>
  <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml"></mapping>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

DAO Layer code:

```
public void saveEmployee(Employee emp){
  Session session = null;
  try{
     File config = new File("/config/hibernate.cfg.xml");
     session = new Configuration().configure(config).buildSessionFactory().openSession();
     Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
     session.saveOrUpdate(emp);
     tx.commit();
     session.flush();
     session.clear();
  }catch(Exception e){
   e.printStacktrace();
 }
}
```

In logs, everything gets completed successfully with no errors, but in the DB records are not getting saved.

Please suggest.It's a normal java application.

Comment: You have to flush before doing a commit. If that doesn't help, I assume that the transaction integration doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Thank you @ChristianBeikov. I will give it a try the way you recommended.